# Some error when using map() in processing

Tags: java, mapping, coordinates, processing

I'm having some trouble when trying to plot some coordinates from a CSV file. I'm taking latitude and longitude, then I convert them using Web Mercator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator#Formulas), after which I'm taking the min and max values and by using the map() function in order to map them to values between 0 and 500. However, I get the following error:

total number of rows: 6606

maxLat = 198987.05; minLat = 198986.94 ; maxLong = 110837.664; minLong = 110836.695
lat & long before mapping: 198986.27 ; 110840.68
lat & long after map(): -6142.857 ; 4112.9033
lat & long after norm(): -6.142857 ; 4.112903

map(NaN, 198986.94, 198987.05, 0, 500) called, which returns NaN (not a number)

map(NaN, 110836.695, 110837.664, 0, 500) called, which returns NaN (not a number)

I'd appreciate any suggestions how to fix the error or improvements on the code.
Thank you in advance.
The code itself:

```
import java.util.Collections;

Table csvFile;

ArrayList<Float>times = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float>latitude = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float>longitude = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float>lap = new ArrayList<Float>();

ArrayList<Float>latitudeCal = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float>longitudeCal = new ArrayList<Float>();

float maxLat = 0;
float maxLong = 0;
float minLat = 0;
float minLong = 0;

void setup() {
  size(600, 800);
  csvFile = loadTable("RRData.csv", "header");

  int totalRows = csvFile.getRowCount();

  println("total number of rows: " + totalRows);

  for (TableRow row : csvFile.rows()) { 
    times.add(row.getFloat("Time"));
    latitude.add(normLat(row.getFloat("Latitude")));
    longitude.add(normLon(row.getFloat("Longitude")));
  }

  maxLat = latitude.get(0);
  maxLong = longitude.get(0);
  maxLat = latitude.get(0);
  maxLong = longitude.get(0);

  // Finding Max Values
  for (int i = 1; i < latitude.size() - 1; i++) {
    maxLat = max(maxLat, latitude.get(i));
    maxLong = max(maxLong, longitude.get(i));
    minLat = min(minLat, latitude.get(i));
    minLong = min(minLong, longitude.get(i));
  }

  println("maxLat = "  + maxLat + "; minLat = " + minLat + " ; maxLong = " + maxLong + "; minLong = " + minLong); 

  println("lat & long before mapping: " + latitude.get(0) + " ; " + longitude.get(0));

  println("lat & long after map(): " + map(latitude.get(0), minLat, maxLat, 0, 1000) + " ; " + map(longitude.get(0), minLong, maxLong, 0, 1000)); // map() doesn't worked as intended

  //Try Normalising
  println("lat & long after norm(): " + norm(latitude.get(0), minLat, maxLat) + " ; " + norm(longitude.get(0), minLong, maxLong));

  // Mapping 
  for (int  i = 0; i < latitude.size() - 1; i++) {
    float num = latitude.get(i);
    float num2 = longitude.get(i);
    //println(num);
    //println(num2);
    latitudeCal.add(map(num, minLat, maxLat, 0, 500));
    longitudeCal.add(map(num2, minLong, maxLong, 0, 500));
  }

}

float normLon(float lon) {
  lon = radians(lon);
  float a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, 10);
  float b = lon + PI;
  return a * b;
}

float normLat(float lat) {
  lat = radians(lat);
  float a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, 10);
  float b = tan(PI / 4 + lat / 2);
  float c = PI - log(b);
  return a * c;
}

void draw() {  
  background(51);
  for (int i = 0; i < times.size() - 1; i++) {
    noFill();
    ellipse(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i), 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [debug your pgoram](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) and narrow your problem down to a [mcve] instead of posting your whole project. Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected? What are the values on that line? Create a new program that just tests that one line with hard-coded values, and edit your post to include this small example that we can run.

Comment: Seems that you are not initializing minLat and minLong appropriately, you set maxXXX twice instead.

Comment: ```i < latitude.size() -1``` you probably need to drop the ```- 1```

Comment: normLon code is more complicated that it needs to be. Eg. ```256 == 2^8``` so it follows that ```a = (1 << 18) / PI```

Comment: Looks to me that either the input Csv contains NaNs or that there is a problem with normXXX or radians operation that result in a NaN